Largest primitive subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_8(\mathbb{C})$ of order $2^a 3^b 5^c$
The paper "Bounds for finite primitive complex linear groups" by M. Collins computes the largest possible value of $[G:Z(G)]$ for $G$ a primitive subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C})$, for each $N$.  I am interested in the $N = 8$ case because complete lists of unimodular primitive subgroups exist for each $N \leq 7$: see W. Feit's "The current situation in the theory of finite simple groups", Section 8.5.
Collins states that the maximum $[G:Z(G)]$ is achieved by the Weyl group of $E_8$, for which $[G:Z(G)] = 348368800$.  Another paper of W. Feit, "On finite linear groups in dimension at most 10", lists some of the primitive groups of $\mathrm{GL}_8(\mathbb{C})$, but only those with order not equal to $2^a 3^b 5^c$.
My question is: what is the largest possible $[G:Z(G)]$ for $G$ a primitive subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_8(\mathbb{C})$ not covered by this list, namely for $G$ with order of the form $2^a 3^b 5^c$? Is there at least a way to bound $[G:Z(G)]$ more strongly in this special case?

In the paper of Feit you mention, he says that the case $|G| = 2^a 3^b 5^c$ follows from work of Huffman and Wales. Presumably means this paper: W. C. Huffman, D. B. Wales, Linear groups of degree eight with no elements of order seven. Illinois J. Math. 20 (1976), no. 3, 519--527. DOI 10.1215/ijm/1256049793

Yes, Feit, Huffman and Wales between them finished off dimensions 8 and 9 in the seventies. Geoff Robinsons's 1981 thesis did dimension 11, and Feit at least dealt with dimension 10 over the rationals. Presumably dimension 10 was finished off at some point, but I don't know the reference. Probably Geoff does.

@DaveBenson : Not sure 10 was ever formally done pre CFSG. I did a bit of work in my thesis towards some 10 dimension cases I needed to understand when doing primitive 11 dimensional groups.

One thing to beware of in these lists is that some of the groups are not really primitive. For example, in Brauers list of 5 dimensional groups, $S5$ and $A5$ are not primitive. I also get a kick out of the fact that the $11$-dimensional irrep of M11 is imprimitive. Safer to stick to quasiprimitive to avoid such pitfalls.

Thank you, I missed that paper of Huffman and Wales!
